# Sharing information between Polymer 1.0 modules

Tags: module, polymer, communication, polymer-1.0

I have two components inside a parent, one component shows me a list, and I want the other component to show me the details of an item of the list. I'm using the List of this demo https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages

since I have these two components

`<list-view data="[[fileData]]" on-item-click="_onItemClick"></list-view>
<full-view on-close="_onClose"></full-view>`

I would like to pass the Id of an item clicked on list-view to the full-view. So what would be the best way to execute an event on "full-view" when an item of "list-view" is clicked? I need to pass information from list-view to full-view.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What about of databinding? @SG_  answer is ok, but it can does using simple databinding, as follows:

```
<list-view data="[[fileData]]" on-item-click="_onItemClick" selected-id="{{idSelected}}"></list-view>
<full-view on-close="_onClose" selected-id="{{idSelected}}"></full-view>
```

Each element models should have a property "Selected ID", to make it possible to perform databinding. In `<full-view>` you must need to add a property as follows:

```
selectedId:{type:String, observer:"selectedIdChanged"}
```

So, when selectedId changes in `<list-view>` will also change in `<full-view>`
Now, you only need to add a new function in `<full-view>` to do something with this changed selectedId

```
selectedIdChanged: function(newValue, oldValue){ 
  if(newValue!= undefined && newValue!=null){
    //do something with selected Id
  } 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give an `id` for both `list-view` and `full-view`, then define & set `data` attribute/property for `<full-view>` from the `_onItemClick`.

```
<list-view id='l_view' data="[[fileData]]" on-item-click="_onItemClick"></list-view>   
<full-view id="f_view" data="{}" on-close="_onClose"></full-view>
```

And in the `script` of parent.

```
_onItemClick: function() {
  this.$.f_view.data = this.$.l_view.selected;//or any attribute of the selected item
  this.$.pages.selected = 1;
},
```